# Why isn't posting a status update to Facebook working?

Tags: python, facebook, oauth

I had a working Python integration to Facebook, using the Graph API and the `https://graph.facebook.com/<<id>>/feed` URL, for about a month.

And then all of a sudden a few days ago, I started getting this back whenever I tried to post a status update:

```
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"}}
```

I'm requesting (and getting) the publish_stream permission, and I can do other things like get friends, pages, etc.

Any ideas?  There's a link here http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=73912 that shows there are others dealing with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I now have my app working again.  I ended up using the JavaScript API from Facebook, using that to login the user, set the cookie, and then I use the Python SDK from Facebook to make the actual status update.  It works.

How this is different from what I was doing (my own Python code for doing the same stuff) is beyond me. The token returned by both the JavaScript and my own Python code are identical.

So it works, but I'm not sure how.